# brightcove player complete event not firing when re-playing the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, brightcove

I add an event listener to a videoplayer inside an onTemplateReady, and on completedCallback I want to replay the video:

videoPlayer.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.COMPLETE, completedCallback);

function completedCallback(){

this.BCP.videoPlayer.seek(0);
  this.BCP.videoPlayer.play();
}

well - the completedCallback gets invoked only the first time! the second time the video is done playing, the completedCallback does not fire. Testing in Chrome on mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal behaviour in the Brightcove Player API. They have a document [here](https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/solutions/capturing-begin-and-complete-events-if-video-replayed) on the subject, including an example of capturing additional "complete" events.

Comment: Unfortunately that is now a dead link :(